# Função em C que apaga determinada string

Tags: c, string

Preciso criar uma função que apaga em `s1` a primeira ocorrência de `s2`.

```
char *StrlDelStr(char *s1,char *s2)
```

Exemplo:

```
char *s = "O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa";
StrlDelStr(s, "xy"); -> "O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa"
StrlDelStr(s, "ra"); -> "O to roeu a rolha da garrafa"
```

Meu código está assim:

```
char *StrlDelStr(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(s1); j++)
        {
            if(s1[i] == s2[j])
                s1[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    char palavras[100] = "Hello World";
    char palavra2[100] = "lo";

    StrlDelStr(palavras, palavra2);
    printf("\n%s\n", palavras);
    return 0;
}
```

Está exibindo `"He    W r d"`. Preciso de uma função em que, em vez de substituir por `' '` todas as ocorrências do *caracter*/*string*, apenas apague
onde ocorre a *string* específica (`s2`).

Comment: Sua pesquisa pela segunda string está errada. Além disso após localizar a segunda string na primeira você não tem que substituir por espaço e sim mover para a esquerda tantas posições quanto forem o total de caracteres da string fornecida no segundo parâmetro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apagar, não tem como. Não tem como fazer as variáveis nas posições que você quer, por exemplo na posição 6,7,8 simplesmente deixarem de existir, o que dá para fazer é identificar onde ocorre `s2` (neste caso, somente a primeira vez), e copiar `s1` até o último caractere antes da primeira ocorrência de `s2`, depois continuar copiando de `s1` *a partir do primeiro caractere que segue após `s2`* que está contida em `s1` até o final.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define TAMANHO 100
char *StrlDelStr(char *s1,char *s2)
{
  char *pt_pos = strstr(s1, s2);
  if(pt_pos == NULL) printf("s1 nao contem s2.\n");
  else
  {
    char aux1[TAMANHO], aux2[TAMANHO];
    *pt_pos=0;
    strcpy(aux1, s1); // a cópia para em pt_pos
    strcpy(aux2, pt_pos+(int)strlen(s2)); // a cópia para no antigo final de s1
    //printf("%s\n%s", aux1,aux2); // para testes
    strcat(aux1, aux2);
    strcpy(s1, aux1);
  }
  return s1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char palavras[TAMANHO] = "O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa";
    char palavra2[TAMANHO] = "ra";

    StrlDelStr(palavras, palavra2);
    printf("\n%s\n", palavras);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@MateusSchroeder/398277).

Answer (score 3):

A resposta aceita tem algo que funciona, mas não é eficiente tendo diversos laços escondidos que tornam a execução bem lenta, assim faz o mesmo de forma eficiente (isto é um mini *parser*):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void StrlDel(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int i = 0;
    int notFound = 1;
    while (s1[i]) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[i + j]; j++);
        if (!s2[j] && notFound) {
            int k;
            for (k = i; s1[k + j]; k++) s1[k] = s1[k + j];
            s1[k] = 0;
            notFound = 0;
        } else i++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char palavras[] = "O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa";
    StrlDel(palavras, "ra");
    printf("\n%s\n", palavras);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/T6c05C). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RemoveSubstring). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/RemoveSubstring.c).